# create a parent record from child before insertion

Tags: apex

I have 3 objects `Imports__c`, `Admin__c` and `Contact` with  `Admin__c` has lookup to `contact`. The `Imports__c` has an External Id field called `Unique__c`.

My requirement is upon the `insert`, `update`  of `Imports__c` records I'm trying to create a `Admin__c` record with the same external id on `Imports__c`.

Now my issue is how can I pull the related contact record and update if it already exists if not then I need to create and also how to populate the `Contactid` on `admin__c`.

Here is the trigger/class where I was able to create the `admin__c` record using upsert.

```
public with sharing class ContactadminCreateHelper {

public static void createadmin(List<Imports__c> Imports){     
    List<Admin__c> insertadminList = new List<Admin__c>();
    List<Contact> insertcontactList = new List<Contact>();
    Set<String> contactIds = new Set<String>();

    for(Imports__c AY : Imports) {
        if (AY.unique__c != NULL) {
            Contact c = new Contact();
           if (AY.Last_or_Family_Name__c!= null) {
                 c.LastName = AY.Last_or_Family_Name__c;
            } else { 
                c.LastName='No Last Name';
            }  
            c.GU_ID__c= AY.GUID__c;
            c.Ethnicity__c= AY.Ethnicity__c;
            insertcontactList.add(c);
             }   
        }
    System.debug('Testing for contact.') ;  
    if ( insertcontactList != null )
    {
        System.debug('About to insert Contact ' + insertcontactList);
        insert insertcontactList ;
        System.debug('AFTER insert of contact Records');
    }

    RecordType adminRecordType;
    List<RecordType> adminRecordTypes = [ select Id, Name, DeveloperName from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Admin__c' ];

    if ( adminRecordTypes != null && adminRecordTypes .size() > 0 )
    {
        adminRecordType = adminRecordTypes [0];        
    }
    else
    {
        adminRecordType = new RecordType(id='01240000000UcwV');
    }

    for(Imports__c AY : Imports) {
        if (AY.unique != NULL) {
            Admin__c adm = new Admin__c();

            adm.unique__c = AY.unique__c;
            adm.Age_at_Time_of_Enrollment__c = AY.Age_at_Time_of_Enrollment__c;
            adm.RecordTypeId = SLMRecordType.Id;
            adm.AY_Application_Term__c= AY.Application_Term__c;
            adm.AY_Admitted_Date__c= AY.AY_Admitted_Date__c;
            adm.AY_Enrolled_Date__c= AY.AY_Enrolled_Date__c;
            adm.Decision_Date__c = AY.Decision_Date__c;
            adm.Enrollment_Decision__c = AY.Enrollment_Decision__c;
            adm.Months_of_work_NEW__c= AY.Months_of_work_NEW__c;
            //adm.ContactName__c=c.Id; this is what i have to do
            insertadmList.add(adm );
             }   
        }
    System.debug('Testing for SML.') ;  
    if ( insertSLMList!= null )
    {
        System.debug('About to insert adm. ' + insertadmList);
        upsert insertadmList unique__c ;
        System.debug('AFTER insert of adm Records');
    }

     }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a version of the code. The trick is the use of `Map<String, Contact> contactsToInsert` to hold the relationship between your unique ID and the contact being inserted.

Then, on the second loop, you can reuse this map to store the values in your code.

PS: I replaced your `== null` with `String.IsEmpty()` as that also checks for empty strings.

PPS: Harcoding a RecordTypeID is a bad practice. but I can't figure out what you have the `new` statement there....  so I left it alone

** NOTE 2/18/16 Per Chat with OP, I adjusted my code to allow existing contacts to be updated **

```
public with sharing class ContactadminCreateHelper {

public static void createadmin(List<Imports__c> Imports){     
  List<Admin__c> insertadminList = new List<Admin__c>();
  Set<String> contactIds = new Set<String>();

  Map<String, Contact> contactsToUpsert = new Map<String, Contact>();

  for(Imports__c AY : Imports) {
      if (! String.isEmpty(AY.unique__c)) {
          Contact c = new Contact();

          if (! String.isEmpty(AY.ContactName__c)) {
            c.Id = AY.ContactName__c;
          }

          if (AY.Last_or_Family_Name__c!= null) {
               c.LastName = AY.Last_or_Family_Name__c;
          } else { 
              c.LastName='No Last Name';
          }  
          c.GU_ID__c= AY.GUID__c;
          c.Ethnicity__c= AY.Ethnicity__c;

          contactsToUpsert.put(AY.Unique__c, c);
           }   
      }
  System.debug('Testing for contact.') ;  

  System.debug('About to insert Contact ' + contactsToUpsert.values());
  upsert contactsToUpsert.values();
  system.debug('AFTER insert of contact Records');


  RecordType adminRecordType;
  List<RecordType> adminRecordTypes = [ select Id, Name, DeveloperName from RecordType where SObjectType = 'Admin__c' ];

  if ( adminRecordTypes != null && adminRecordTypes .size() > 0 )
  {
      adminRecordType = adminRecordTypes [0];        
  }
  else
  {
      adminRecordType = new RecordType(id='01240000000UcwV');
  }

  for(Imports__c AY : Imports) {
      if (! String.isEmpty(AY.unique__c)) {
          Admin__c adm = new Admin__c();

          adm.unique__c = AY.unique__c;
          adm.Age_at_Time_of_Enrollment__c = AY.Age_at_Time_of_Enrollment__c;
          adm.RecordTypeId = SLMRecordType.Id;
          adm.AY_Application_Term__c= AY.Application_Term__c;
          adm.AY_Admitted_Date__c= AY.AY_Admitted_Date__c;
          adm.AY_Enrolled_Date__c= AY.AY_Enrolled_Date__c;
          adm.Decision_Date__c = AY.Decision_Date__c;
          adm.Enrollment_Decision__c = AY.Enrollment_Decision__c;
          adm.Months_of_work_NEW__c= AY.Months_of_work_NEW__c;
          if (contactsToUpsert.containsKey(AY.Unique__c)) {
            adm.ContactName__c= contactsToUpsert.get(AY.Unique__c).id;
          }

           insertadmList.add(adm );
           }   
      }
  System.debug('Testing for SML.') ;  
  if ( insertSLMList!= null )
  {
      System.debug('About to insert adm. ' + insertadmList);
      upsert insertadmList unique__c ;
      System.debug('AFTER insert of adm Records');
  }

   }
}
```

Comment: If you have some sort of "ExternalID" in your contact object, we can make this code even better. Let me know if that's the case and I can rearrange the code.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian : I was able to populate the contactid but the issue is there is no external id on contact which I can use from imports__c

Comment: This code should then, hopefully, help anyway. Please don't forget to upvote (and mark as accepted) if this helped you, so others can benefit.

Comment: Sebastian: Since I dont have the external id on contact. Can I use a combination of Fistname+Lastname+Email to update the records if doesnt exist should be able to insert it?

Comment: After the code I sent, what's missing?

Comment: right now im doing only insert on contact but i would like to do update based on the combination of these 3 fields

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35921/discussion-between-sebastian-kessel-and-salesforce-learner).